# get the token from header using volley in android

Tags: android, json

I am developing the android app and i want to get the token from header using volley which is in server json response and store it in sq-lite for maintaining the session of user,i search everywhere bt i am not getting how to retrieve the token from json,please help me about this issue

this is my json response

```
{ "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI5ODkzMjY3OTQ0IiwiYXVkIjoid2‌​ViIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA1OD‌​EwNTQ5LCJpYXQiOjE1MD‌​UyMDU3NDl9.cf9QGwp7z‌​LVSTuiunClkauTFEXe6j‌​tcNCxzqIntEtmWTDfLqA‌​D3nKiXIf-fg0vEV_74SO‌​cPVYxDcTUwCZqntVA" }
```

Comment: Can you post the json?

Comment: please share your json response

Comment: this is my json responce {
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI5ODkzMjY3OTQ0IiwiYXVkIjoid2ViIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA1ODEwNTQ5LCJpYXQiOjE1MDUyMDU3NDl9.cf9QGwp7zLVSTuiunClkauTFEXe6jtcNCxzqIntEtmWTDfLqAD3nKiXIf-fg0vEV_74SOcPVYxDcTUwCZqntVA"
}

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("your json string");
 String token= jsonObject.optString("token");
```

Comment: @NikhilPatil Welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
  JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String access_token= jsonObject.optString("access_token");
                 Log.v("####","hellow token  " + access_token);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Try this